# Get rid of main-{scalaVersion}-Directories in sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I've changed the default src directory according to: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/defaultpaths.html

to:

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src/main"
javaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src/main"

scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src/test"
javaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src/test"

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "res"
resourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "res/test"
```

Now whenever intellij/idea reloads it adds back `main-2.11` and `test-2.11` folders.

I want to get rid of those, but I've not found a way for now. Any ideas?

**edit:** I've already deleted the whole .idea and other folders for IntelliJ and re-imported the project with the .sbt file. Still no luck. On every startup or change of the .sbt these annoying folders are re-created. Grrr!

Comment: What intellij version are you using? How did you create/import the project? You may have some leftovers in your project structure.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg: I created the project a while ago and assumed that intellij would load in the information from the sbt anyway (as it does). Can I somehow delete the leftovers without having to reimport the whole project? I'm using the community-edition 14.1.4 (latest one in the archlinux repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might rather lie with sbt. If you open sbt console and enter

```
show sourceDirectories
```

the result might still include the *scala-2.11* folders.

If so the following lines would fix that:

```
sourceDirectories in Compile <<= (sourceDirectories in Compile) { dirs =>
  dirs.filterNot(_.absolutePath.endsWith("-2.11")) 
}

sourceDirectories in Test <<= (sourceDirectories in Test) { dirs => 
  dirs.filterNot(_.absolutePath.endsWith("-2.11")) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the string is just left in > target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main but that does not matter. I wonder tho, why this even happens!